# Can we use a Unix Timestamp as _timestamp field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When we create time-based indices, elasticsearch/kibana need a field named "_timestamp".

I found that this field should be a string.

But in my log, Unix Timestamp is a necessary segment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can store unix timestamp in `Date` type fields. But make sure you use proper `format` like `epoch_millis` for timestamp in millis and `epoch_second` for timestamp in seconds.

Example mapping for `timestamp` field which stores unix timestamp in seconds.

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my-type": {
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date)